# Is there an analytical solution to the integral of Weibull cdf $1-e^{-(x/a)^b}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

As part of a bigger exercise I need to try and find the integral of $$1-\exp\{-(x/a)^b\} dx.$$

Note: I can't quite get LaTex to format the equation properly but the exponential should be raised to the whole bracketed term!

I am reasonably sure there is an analytical solution as the above equation is the cdf of a Weibull distribution and it is derived by integrating the pdf of the Weibull, which has a very similar term in it $$\frac{b}{a}(x/a)^{b-1}\exp\{-(x/a)^b\}$$ and provides the neat analytical answer above. The problem being that I can't find anywhere which explains the actual steps from pdf to cdf so I can apply them to this problem, it seems to just be taken as given.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how I would do this?

Alternatively, my ultimate goal is an analytical expression to work out the expected value of a Weibull distribution specifically between two points of the distribution, say y and z, not over the whole distribution. I have used integration by parts to get the formula for the integral of x.f(x) but this leaves me needing to find the integral above. If there is another, easier way someone knows of to find this value, or could suggest that would also be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: use `\frac{a}{b}` for $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: You can use brackets `e^{x/a}` to make a whole expression in superscript. Please check if my edits reflect what you wanted to write.

Comment: Yes thanks to both of you. That is what I was trying to write!

Comment: Actually, just realised I had omitted a minus sign before the bracket in the exponential term. It's now correct.

Comment: $e^{-x^2}$ is well-known not to have an elementary antiderivative, and (if I interpret correctly) that's just a very simple case of your question, $a=1$, $b=2$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, you have interpreted the equation correctly. Can I ask, would that mean that there is no way to get to an expression for the integral of the first equation? Or is there some, I guess non-elementary(?), method which I could employ?

Comment: The function does not have an elementary antiderivative. It does not have an antiderivative expressible in closed form in terms of the 4 arithmetical operations, powers, square roots, cube roots, exponentials, logarithms, trig functions, and/or inverse trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%281-exp%28-%28x/a%29%5Eb%29) the integral can be expressed with the incomplete gamma function:
$$\int\left( 1 - \exp{\left(-\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^b\right)}\right) dx  = \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\left(\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^b \right)^{-\frac{1}{b}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{b}, \left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^b\right) + x + C$$
The incomplete gamma function can be assumed to be known in the context of statistical distributions, e.g. as the CDF of the Chi-square or Gamma distribution.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a big step in the right direction. I will need to learn a little more about gamma functions as I've not come across them before but this gives me something to work with. Thanks again!